# Calculus delta epsillon

Tags: calculus

I'm not taking this calculus course, but I'm interested because I couldn't find the answer.  I have concluded 3/5 of the statements to be true:

Where am I wrong and why?

a is true because $|x-3| \ge 0$ and $x \ne 3$ excludes the equal case
b is false because of the possibility that $x=3$

c is false because it reduces to $-0.8 \lt x-3 \lt -0.2$

d is false because we only know the range of values, not their exact

e is false because it includes the case where $|x-3| \ge 1$

f is true because 0.5 is less than 1

g is false because this isnt stated

h is true because $0.1 \lt 0.2$

i is false because the range is wrong

j is false because it includes the equality case for the conclusion

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints :

c) If $-0.8< x-3  <-0.2$ then $0<0.2<|x-3|<0.8<1$ since $x-3$ is negative the absolute value of $x-3$ is equal to $-(x-3)$. Consequently
$$-0.8< x-3  <-0.2 \Rightarrow  0.8> -(x-3)=|x-3|>0.2$$

j) Be careful : if you know that $g(x)> 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ then all you can deduce is $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x) \ge 1$ (the strict inequality is false). Furthermore, I might have misunderstood what you said for this question but if for you the correct answer should be $4.9 < L < 5.1$, the weaker conclusion $4.9 \le L \le 5.1$ is also true, no?

Comment: How did you put the absolute value back on $x-3$? I am confused about this

Comment: Also, isn't the weaker conclusion false because L should never be equal to 4.9 or 5.1?

Comment: For the absolute value, please see my edit.

Comment: Your argument is : if $L = \lim_{x\to 3}$, then $4.9< L < 5.1$ (this is wrong as I already said). But if it were true, you agree with me that $4.9<L<5.1$ implies $4.9\le L \le 5.1$ so we have, $L = \lim_{x\to 3}$, then $4.9< L < 5.1$ then $4.9\le L \le 5.1$.

Answer (score 1):

(j) For all $0<|x-3|<1$

$|5-L|\le |5-f(x)|+|f(x)-L| \le 0.1+|f(x)-L|$

Take limit when $x\rightarrow 3$ obtain

$|5-L|\le 0.1 \Rightarrow 4.9\le L\le 5.1$